# Project explorer no longer is grouped

Tags: excel, vba

For Some reason.. the project Explorer seems to have grouped up..

[image]

Is this is any way I can display sheets, forms, modules, class Module..

Kindly help..

Sam

Comment: Click that little yellow folder at the top

Comment: Thanks.. got it..(I've been dumb)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I got it..

Just had to click on toggle folders

[image]